# Spring JPA/Hibernate returns random last page?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have recently upgraded a service from:

- JDK8 -> JDK11
- Spring Boot 1.5 -> Spring Boot 2.3

Since then, an integration test fails in a weird way, such that when a query is executed (pageable). From the 100 results i.e. 5 pages, the 5th page is always a random selection.

The result looks looks like this:

Page 0 (ids [0, 19])

```
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_0', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_1', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_2', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_3', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_4', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_5', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_6', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_7', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_8', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_9',...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_10', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_11', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_12', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_13', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_14', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_15', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_16', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_17', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_18', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_19', ...]
```

Pages 1-3 continue as above.

However the last page (#4) is different (expected ids [80, 99]) :

```
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_25', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_94', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_0', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_31', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_62', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_13', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_69', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_33', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_64', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_52', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_86', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_24', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_16', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_22', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_89', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_50', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_57', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_92', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_29', ...]
[SomeObject@... 'inttest_log_device_15', ...]
```

The executed code is:

```java
someRepository.findAll(predicate, pageable);
```

Where the repository simply extends Spring's `JpaRepository` and `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`. The `predicate` is a `BooleanBuilder` with some filter criteria.

The code furthermore always worked perfectly well. It just started making problems once I've upgraded.

Comment: And you do have an explicit order by (sort order) in your query? Else it uses whatever the database returns.

Comment: @M.Deinum  the sorting did it! Thanks a bunch. If you want, you can write an actual answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an explicit ordering, you are basically at the perils of DBMS what it returns. When using paging you should always have an explicit ordering.

You can do this by adding a `Sort` to the `Pageable` you pass in.

```java
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(0, 1, Direction.ASC, "id);
```

Something like that should do the trick.